# Dot notation on nested objects not in Mongoose schema

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a mongoose schema with a providerData object:

```
... , providerData: {}, ...
```

and I would like to query for documents based on the IDs of objects in the `providerData` object.

So I assumed I would have to use dot notation like so:

```
    User.findOne({ providerIDString: providerID }, function(err, user) {...});
```

where

```
    providerIDString is a string like 'providerData.facebook.id'
    providerID is the providerData.facebook id
```

However the query keeps returning no results even though

```
db.users.find({"providerData.facebook.id":"THEFACEBOOKID"})
```

in the mongodb shell returns the correct document

Am I correct to assume this is happening because `providerData.facebook` and `providerData.facebook.id` are not defined in the User schema?

Does this mean I have to add them to the schema or is there a way to use dot notation on nested objects not in the mongoose schema?

Comment: Show a document that you expect to match. And the full query you are actually using. That will be a lot clearer than your attempt at explain here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm guessing that you have input like:

```
var providerIdString = 'providerData.facebook.id',
    facebookId = "THEFACEBOOKID";
```

In which case you use:

```
var query = {};
query[provoderIdString] = facebookId;
```

Then:

```
db.users.find(query);
```

And behold! It works.

That is how you construct objects from variable names in JavaScript.

Comment: The bracket `[]` notation is how you interpose variable names and other "text" that does not suit JavaScript Object Notation. Oh and [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) when you are done.